# Python Request, UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0421' in position 1228799: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I am trying to request some information from Coincodex via Python:

```
url = "https://coincodex.com/apps/coincodex/cache/all_coins.json"
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text.encode('utf-8'))
print(data)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0421' in position 1228799: character maps to <undefined>`

I have tried `text.encode` and `content.decode`, but I still can't find a solution that works for me.

Comment: could be something not compatible with the encoding
try to just use
`data=json.loads(response.text)`
does that work?

Comment: I originally had this, but I kept getting the same error. Answers online suggested using, text.encode or content.decode, but I still get the same issue

Comment: You don't need explicit decoding.  `encode` will never work, it does the *opposite* of what you want. I can't reproduce any problem with just `response.json()`.

Comment: In fact, the error you got says that `loads` tried to use a non-Unicode codepage to *de*code the *bytes* returned by `encode`, and failed when it encountered values that are only valid in Unicode

Answer (score 0):

`response.text` is a string already. There's nothing to *de*code, you can parse it directly. *En*coding means converting strings to bytes using a specific codepage.

You can write just `json.loads(request.text)`:

```
url = "https://coincodex.com/apps/coincodex/cache/all_coins.json"
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data[0]['symbol'])
```

This prints :

```
BTC
```

Unicode isn't some kind of escape sequence. UTF16, UTF8, are ways of encoding characters to one or more bytes. This page is UTF8 just like most web pages. That's why I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` knowing it will appear just fine without resorting to escape sequences.

When you access `response.text` the `requests` module *de*codes the HTTP response sent from the server using the character set (another name for codepage) specified in the `Content-Type` header.

You can read *and* parse the response as JSON directly by using `response.json()` instead of `response.text` :

```
url = "https://coincodex.com/apps/coincodex/cache/all_coins.json"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data[0]['symbol'])
```

This time I got `APX3`.

Comment: Yes, I originally had this, but if I print(Data), i still receive the same error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0421' . I want to print a list of all symbols.

Comment: @Charmalade I get no error at all. That's why I *know* there's an array and a `symbol`. If you got an error, it's due to a different code or URL. Unless you use Python 2?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.13. and I still receive UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 3024402: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: print(data[0]['symbol']) works for me, but obviously I need to access data

Comment: But you *do* access `data`. If you type `print(data)` it works fine. I repeat - that's how I found out about the contents. I had no idea what that JSON contained. I called `print(data)` and show a long array of objects. Then I called `print(data[0])` and show there's a `symbol` key

Comment: I appreciate, it is working for you. It is not working for me. I am receiving the data, but I can't print it because there is a symbol in the data that my machine doesn't like.

Comment: It's working for everyone. If it didn't, thousands of developers that use `requests` to make API calls would complain. This is far too basic a call, shown in *all* courses and tutorials.

Comment: XD. Are you really trying to tell me it's working on my machine?

Comment: I'm saying you're doing something wrong because it works on everyone else's machine. Did you actually try to print `response.json()`? What's the *actual full error message?*, including the stack trace? That would show *which* calls were at fault and maybe where the call started. Although this is far easier in 3.10

Comment: Can you type just `requests.get(url).json()` in a Python console? That will retrieve and parse the response at once. Does the error happen every time you do that? Or some of the time?

Comment: Yes I have. If I run print(data[0]['symbol']), I get APX3. If I run print(data) I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0421' in position 1272748: character maps to <undefined>. There is one specific symbol preventing me from printing it

Comment: `requests.get(url).text[1272748:1272800]` returns `,"price_change_1H_percent":0,"price_change_1D_percen'` right now

Comment: rewriting as print(requests.get("https://coincodex.com/apps/coincodex/cache/all_coins.json").json()), I get a similar error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 3213281: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: And `requests.get(url).text[3213280:3213290]` is `nt":0,"pri`

Comment: Perhaps I should shout remove the elements with the errors

Comment: I am able to print the list via looping: for i in range(0,len(data)):
    print(data[i]['symbol'])